# VueJs: How to create an orgchart

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

I am trying to create an orgchart like this:

[image]

but I am stuck at this point:

[image]

I tried connecting the flexboxes with Svg's but wasnt getting the results i hoped.

My code so far:
in App.vue

```
<v-container grid-list-md>      
  <!-- Display Nodes -->        
    <v-layout row justify-center v-for="layer in maxLayer">                     
       <displaynode :node="node" v-for="node in sortedNodes" v-if="node.layer == layer"></displaynode>  
    </v-layout>    
</v-container>
```

in DisplayNode.vue

```
<template>
   <div ref="node" class="node">  
   <!-- Node Representation of a goal -->
     <v-card color="deep-purple lighten-1" class="white--text" hover raised> 
       <v-card-text>
         <h2>{{node.name}}</h2>        
       </v-card-text>
       <v-card-actions >           
        <editnode :node="node"></editnode>
      </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
  <addnode :parent="node" align="center"></addnode>
  <h2 align="center"> {{node.rel}} </h2>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: @iOS: please do not duplicate images in your edits. A link or an image is enough, we don't need both. Thank you.

Comment: I think for drawing figures and diagrams like the one you wanted required a more sophisticated drawing library, something along the lines of d3.

Comment: You can use 3rd party plugin.

Comment: use getorgchart

Comment: Thanks, i am going to use getorgchart. How do i use an external library in Vue?

Comment: Yes. I agree with Terry. You should turn to 3rd party lib for building up tree-like orgchart.